# 7zip cli kills itself. Why?

Tags: linux, command-line, archiving, 7-zip

I have 1 TB huge directory on debian/ext3. I need to 7zip it and then transfer it to another computer windows/ntfs. I use the following command, but in the end it says `Killed`. Any idea whats wrong?

```
7za a archive -mx0 -v250m Files/

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)
Scanning

Creating archive archive.7z

Killed
```

Comment: I'd say Out of memory?

Comment: check your system log to see if oom killed it.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue. I solved it by reducing the number of threads & dictionary size:

```
# note that you should use [-mmt4] OR [-mmt2]
7za a -m0=lzma2 [-mmt4|-mmt2] archive.7z Files/
```

For ultra compression try the following:

```
# note that you should use [-mmt4] OR [-mmt2]
7za a -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 [-mmt2|-mmt4] archive.7z Files/
```